# How to increase code performance? multithread or Tasks in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I have the following two functions

```
   void ParserData(List<DataObject> MyObjcets){

        //loop over MyObjects

        List<ResultObject> Results = new List<ResultObject> ();
        foreach(var Obj in MyObjects){
        //do some computation and add it to an instance of ResultObject 
        ResultObject R = new ResultObject();

        Results.Add(R);
        if(Results.count >= 2000){
           //call a function that will insert Results to MYSQL DB 
           InsertDATA(Results);
           //create empty Results list 
           Results = new List<ResultObject> ();
        }
         //
        }
```

Insert Function

```
void InsertDATA(List<ResultObject> Results){
foreach(var R in Results){
      .....
    //Insert Object to MYSQLDB
    }
}
```

I was thinking to make this code faster, but I am not sure the best way to go. the reason I am committing insertion every 2000 is because the system runs out of memory after that. 
is there a way that after I send the data to be inserted, I can move on the do more computation while the data I sent is being inserted, and not wait till the insertion is complete?

any suggestions to make this code faster will be appreciated.

Comment: The best suggestion is use a profiler on your program and see what it is actually spending it's time on.

Comment: Check out `dotTrace` https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ There is a 30-Days Free Trial

Comment: If it's this trivial and the data is in the same table, you might be better offf using batch inserts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided - you can use `async/await` approach for database method.

Make your database insertion method asynchronous

```
Task SaveResultAsync(ResultObject result)
{
    var query = "INSERT ...."
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(conn, query)
    {
        // command.AddParameter for values you want to insert
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

Then you can run every query by its own without waiting for other queries and results

```
async Task ParserData(List<DataObject> MyObjcets)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach(var Obj in MyObjects)
    {
        //do some computation and add it to an instance of ResultObject 
        ResultObject result = new ResultObject();
        var task = SaveResultAsync(result );

        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Of course you will need to change signature of `ParseData` method to asynchronous too.
After changing signature, `async/await` starts spread over your application as zombies :)

Comment: I will try this, thank you so much. one thing through, I am not returning anything from SaveResult but the compiler is complaining about return statement. do I need return statement in SaveResult function??

Comment: Asynchronous method always return `Task`. If method return some value it will be `Task<string>`, if method is `void` (your case) it will return `Task`. The idea is that asynchronous method return object which contain information about status of the task.

Comment: Still not sure how to return a task. What should I write at the end of savereuslt function?

Comment: Check updated answer for `SaveresultAsync` method. In this you don't need to return anything. `await` keyword will do the magic. In cases when you don't want wait for task completion you can return `Task`: `return command.ExecuteNonQuery`. Every asynchronous method return `Task`. `await` keyword will "unwrap" Task to the returned value or void. In case of exception `await` will throw exception